# default_scope :order => :index does not works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a simple models

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :parts
end
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   default_scope :order => :index
end
```

Each part has it's own index, to be ordered inside of the Item in question.

When i load parts for the item in ItemsController.show method, the parts are not ordered.

This is what happens in db:

```
[4;35;1mPart Load (0.7ms)[0m   [0mSELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE ("parts".item_id = 165968587) [0m
```

Is't the "index" word reserved ?

Why ordering is not happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work, however you could also try something different:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :parts,
            :order => :index
end
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works. But it only works, when i write it as: has_many :parts, :order => "\"index\"". Possible, "index" word is reserved. The only thing, i'm thinking about - will it cross-database or not...